# I guess it's not possible to use web sockets, can AJAX polling be used with AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I am looking at using AMP for a page which has a section that gets updated via websockets currently. I assume this isn't possible with AMP, so as a fallback can we use AJAX polling, or can it only be static content?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use web sockets or AJAX polling in AMP.
However your use case might be better handled with the upcoming amp-live-list component: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2762

Comment: I did some digging and found that issue. Definitely something I'll look into when it's ready. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only static content. You could add a button to re-direct to a non-AMP JS-based page to do the polling. If you have consistent menus, then the polling page could be equivalent to a pop-up with a return to the AMP page.

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can't use ajax in amp page pages but we can try same implementation using amp-list tag

```
    <amp-list src="http://localhost:3000/comments" 
        [src]="productsState.items" 
        width="320"
        height="144"
        [height]="productsState.items.length * 24"
        class="m1">
<template type="amp-mustache">
  <strong>Product</strong>: {{name}}
  <strong>Price</strong>: ${{price}}
</template>
```