# Is AJAX to load embeds possible in AMP?

Tags: ajax, embed, amp-html

Quick question: Is it possible to dynamically load content like

```
<amp-twitter
  data-tweetid="611193269532295168"
  layout="responsive">
```

via `AJAX` into an `AMP` article?

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, it is not possible but AMP - [LIVE-UPDATING AMPS](https://amphtml.wordpress.com/2016/07/26/live-updating-amps/)

> a new AMP component that updates page content dynamically without additional navigation or reload: readers looking at an earlier version of the page will simply see new updates as they come in.

[image]

[image]

> The [amp-live-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-live-list) component adds support for publishing live updates to AMP pages as new content becomes available in the source document. This works great for implementing live blogs.
>
> In other words, the AMP runtime will poll the server for updates to the origin document, fetching itself. The server can returns the entire AMP page [or parts of it](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-live-list/amp-live-list-server-side-filtering.md), and the runtime updates the page in-place seamlessly.

You can also check a related SO question can [AJAX polling be used with AMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36450831/5995040)  that discusses how to dynamically load updates for the AMP pages.

Hope this helps.