# amp-form: always trigger page reload on submit on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I have a form which displays something depending on the response from server.

Success response would also display the results of query while error response would display errors and dynamically change css styles to emphasize elements.

Code works on desktop.

However in mobile, it always trigger page reload/refresh on submit and would not display elements inside `<div submit-error>` and `<div submit-error>`.

Browsers tested on mobile (always trigger page reload/refresh):

- Safari 14.4.2 mobile
- Chrome 87.0.4280.77

Here's a simple html code to reproduce:

```
<form method="POST" action-xhr="/api/some-path" target="_top">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <div submit-success>
         <h2>Success</h2>
    </div>

    <div submit-error>
         <h2>SError</h2>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior or make it in such a way it behaves like `event.preventDefault()` on non-amp pages?

If no, then is the AMP way of submitting forms in mobile always need to reload/redirect to another page?

Comment: if you want to send the data to server without refresh you should use ajax, and then in success and failure of your response you could run any code you want. but when you submit a form it would be refreshed.

Comment: you could also change the response from the server so it would be shown exactly like what you want based on the success or failure...

Comment: @arashyousefi can you show how you would do this in such a way it would be a valid amphtml?

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682349/is-ajax-to-load-embeds-possible-in-amp

Comment: I think using amp-live-list instead of using a form would be an anti-pattern. I need input from users that suits perfectly on forms.

Comment: 3rd party deployment seems to work fine.
Issue persists when built on my machine accessed over the network 
(laptop server, accessed using mobile on same network)
any thoughts on this?

Comment: sorry, I just tried to help. I have no expreience on amp but i think you should consider searching better keywords. the link i gave you is just one solution. you should be able to even do it your way. but you should look for right sources. again sorry.